# How to create an Xlookup function (similair to Excel)

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, performance

**Edit: I have added `table3`, which is closer to my real life use case and timings of the code**

**Edit 2: I have added `table4`, which is much bigger and tested more timings**

I have a list of associations:

```
table = {<|"Letter" -> "A", "Number" -> 1, 
    "Fruit" -> "Apple"|>, <|"Letter" -> "B", "Number" -> 2, 
    "Fruit" -> "Banana"|>, <|"Letter" -> "C", "Number" -> 3, 
    "Fruit" -> "Cherry"|>};
```

Given a row entry and specifying in which column to find this entry, I would like to find the corresponding row entry of another column as quickly as possible

For example

```
xlookup["Banana","Fruit","Number",table] (*2*)
```

I have tried the following:

```
xlookup[lookupValue_, lookupArrayHeader_String, 
   returnArrayHeader_String, listOfAssociations_List] := 
  AssociationThread[
    listOfAssociations[[All, lookupArrayHeader]] -> 
     listOfAssociations[[All, returnArrayHeader]]][lookupValue];
```

and

```
xlookup2[lookupValue_, lookupArrayHeader_String, 
  returnArrayHeader_String, listOfAssociations_List] :=
 With[
  {row = 
    First@FirstPosition[listOfAssociations[[All, lookupArrayHeader]], 
      lookupValue]},
  Lookup[
    listOfAssociations, {lookupArrayHeader, returnArrayHeader}][[row, 
    2]]
  ];
```

But both are slow when I have a large `table` and the function gets called many times.

I feel I should be able to get a 10x increase if I memoize part of the function or a save a lookup table to memory.

---

**Edit**

Sample data that is closer to my real world use case:

```
table3 = 
 Uncompress[
  "1:eJzt3c+P3FYdAPBtsg1p+\
iNtk6ZJKeEheigS2zQpqsQB6Nbr2Zl1ZmbHntl4Rwhp8nbs2Wza2jNjr2cREhckEAdAnMo\
JiQu9wJUjgn+g4sKFA70hcUKCC+LA+9qzu5P3PONnj3/t9uVQbbJvxvZ7X3/6fc/vPX/\
l4Ueq8e2VlZXRKvnP/f3R2LgFf3uW/Gd9NPoI7/fG+x99aFw4LqI6j/vaFfJD3Rl5Zn+\
IHU97hvx1tyspjTW13aCKXiI/6HjguaZ2kfyoHI6oAvBhvd+blnma/\
K1pGrZDlXoefnCHQ3die0eNowPsl9wdY8OjSr5EfpA+\
GIwN5xB3jMGHfcO08T6UpgpehQMfDXuudVJMWw2uhL6IV8gPDbeDPdMeNFyn07c8+\
8CysTn88o/+2frD9+69F1JBxyfRaPhXrnYkqtA1+FZ78BCbFdc5bFuuO+xh89D/\
8C66i8j1TryjBZd3+hH/AEzdXz65QnIO8Kud3bl1cPpdT8HhQ67nQd/18LpjeyPtCxAd+\
uROr/8WVfCF44ITtW+a2Bkc+edGClMFn4OLN42J7RyefmevPxpji46Q5/y2dzzTGHi6vY/\
3f9tjGvPytC7h98MV/88fv0OVeZn8UCMtiFv26MAyjrZdc2h4/\
rVtVxW1UddkpRLyGf969AM8sPfsgeHZruMH3913vTF9qq/CD+SWGDXclmtZhjkTKt+\
//rvNz47G9FnBmUP7y8YQ+62rtrUG8iMbbfe9vompD1w/CRt97Jrek0FA4oYq/\
uJMwMAx4FjaDfjtmFzNoYvarmFOkLuHoDnCDiaTa36Mj78jCJfwcELzL5+6FeMjA/\
WkalU5T2P8X7kmXXBpYuA6uIn52Z/+8+Z3f/\
9O6sSo2RCjchJDlxPE5EPMi8fEQGAnEEbNVRg6SrIUBgrr2kZbUlJABmJNs60RxnRYssxA\
Wd096mEjdWngYgpPZvRspNE5paHLCWnykebasTTT2E6AjZ4rNnSg5IBNR1Iqy2MD/\
7wdQ5ohNqy0pYEr4ZbmVx/Dn8/\
o8Flemk4m0nQ4pLngH34xNZd8PVp3GtzStKKkgSOM4MZBnutEYvPvpxZjE7TLJ5zYQDS1J\
LXe4ZRm/wobTguQCYu+\
J4C5SQPTIXGdRJlOnsrQMcKljN9w8ZW5Eiij1VNABorfx4euTdPBMnMpYIYturQyOrkUbm\
Wu/PU31re++YvU85m2loky9IXNU6at8SU0Vi+9hAZ+Y/\
VG9BcywPz9l6sLgZmTNxQDDFcW8yqNDMnqExhDYiZHY+jq4jHmtDaSObN1PoaAL/\
iXUnifaWs3C2O26FOYZwxTA6LTlE+\
n6TZUPmlJ1IWbv4onaNd2PGyejgjHUYdEUX7qMMHFo07S/tPpM6dOkz5uOcDx/5/Z0Fr0/\
63ndqDI5RTOTic+O2z9P8GOX2SX152OcKcYd64HLRmIk/DhU4dPm9egqO042DhwLXuE/\
HsPHRfjFSc8rrIkx39ooshaRVnbVZc0J0ZnCoKwahxgGEqG5DNte+B0q/\
o9XnrC8qgQdupMDS1ip6rHZodtAibbqfKMEIcWDBm3UZXWnQ6dYM1Bh5SNQgcib+\
jXLtfAzR5b6Wd44OaloP2QajiuZSSQhsQLjzS3g0CcHmCE1vU1ckjSCqQb56tD1/vC/\
IaJkiyxOc1vJK125vMbOE2pTY98LWMMxJPUN10Hf0Cf7cKH3kpsaNj6fwIa+\
Ncj9trmUaMq0dRI61VuakjZlKn5bwQ1K/4f3hynaGq+\
NBMnqGNbFqmWxAkOiR7eBOfkmC1s2o99UkaoRm4GbnLC75kszfEzDaUm6ZLUWp6dOE/\
AocmOc5xM7FHpkgXYU38/G3uYa5tnT/19YU+e9tycdeAkhY/\
PDgmcnNlhQipLdoANtbrektbYTsOMOX50OqRO6NuHfRYeIkP45L6QguHeQBnH4Bw+\
ZgrOxSa8OMVNaJmFSU7851NszTO9qQWXT6U4Ec+\
n4JvhKXivZ6X3HBzu9bZBPhM9iPPja4uRKdUzqkhkXgtaD7VJdXlINfsTnPARlcr3iIruV\
AE5Bxgd31w2jkVNm5kJy0PN6c2bbBinqcCDZOFNOt48iD96k6Y3DzhGb8Ab3rSGQ5uYaU3\
UtJsV/89ZSWtengLQNEYJpXmQbPgmuTQwDbSZszOnaY28QffiBDNJ0ppKbGbYml8iraHvN\
pHWZIjM7aD1pE1UsQ/HHtIfYfxkehMrtalwgfM6HBQ/Qhuu+RB1sDkwHM+\
2cOxnU6HhkrU3EGQwYFyXm5DbCHRSQacbvy+\
VJjpdrr7U5M6hwY8O1wPxpmFZHJnN9jcunh10uB6Ev34Cj7wBk3B6ronWK3rrOAuJw06Xr\
0eVJjtMwGTNDoQEdKcqdVlkOimhs9kuFJ3NtkAnX3ROs50q3iOn1bcMUoXQw3It28GoTc/\
6WMgOCZ+82anSIZM1OxBostJYryoVoo+AJx145Gah8Mh0H52C55mV6UhOp+3R+X/\
yPhZ0RcK+kXXnz4t7WP/75F9/qT98Lyt3rsZyJ0YPq4sd8wh1+z1E7u++aVj+\
0E68HhaJnLzNYaIlD3Mq9fuSqjQaFWmNnVk7Yw6EagWevnnu4KFgZzE7FTX+Ygem8pOzU+\
Hci6KIBVXvPb841wkm/\
v2kHOZw5To3gtZDcHcg1fA8cvvHH0ImIcPjzRfht9OVDUtyU0ky13jZnlVFUuSu1tQFNul\
h0y0Wm67AJj9srh9jAys3u+7hKAk13bypYRYCZU2N/6xKUzWFdKTontyMM/\
BvurtHT3oTxNBPquLnM2y9L/GkKiKfKf6B+D32Tp+\
FJqzvkhYyK7GQiexF3QjaDvbT0lXS6AM3yXoGlS+\
bge94cj0Dgtsx1ioGJjiytiWYkUZiWBa4pIJLo1hcaDRKlL/8/\
NPzOTDs89KQkdyHdkD3SPt7hFnfgVjMNPJjhg6TfJjZ3pYkwUwazGwVm8NslXhM5vHfLnB\
0kz4+Q8zcWnkiiyENv7eHkwzLbOWXyDARkrUwPhHrTaUqgEkDGD3JQ+\
70gNEjHnIXCcwPf3r5/OYxBJhpHnP3Ltp1TWuC9P4h3WyLN+\
zje8CdhjJMmGStjL8dwnq7LVXX9OamYGZZZrRqbGbYek/\
OjEYvkQwdi5nceXiYmjIxx2JusXd7ebeW4MZGJ/d9Aw/\
GDjmOZR2h6UHxBFX7vV4cbEgA8WDjH5S0gXHgmqejvujNR8YI6fWOtPm1OOw0tnNmB9pNr\
WlrndaC50zCHM6+U/xJw2y9L9F3ipg0DC3a2eBf503KpmzODxabk+\
X4b8rrFG4FbTddmVAzrGHCNVFbfHOFoYnafXNkoI5BamFkhyVOoaxAiW1yi+\
cMC9RWU6u01tTOgmwGaqDWpGeSCVgoWJpJJsqkl8w0IwZljufnecjdT28NFJyvZ7pHIV96\
zjc4h5xC1WCKXtMl3aS7b7+NGlARWt8Z4FHczUCbfGMzN2fvp5NE5uuo7gzo6l+\
YwjDBkrU0/qBCvXKf9JyENSmMz9QLtUavl92aqM1Ag67KXjlmy0Rac+\
3EGt22HmMzyXsU6rkCw0RI1sBABNQqsMJyvbN4xYEghouYWrErumsRK7qLJyZqP6yzlc68\
snK84qBmkQM4/WECZGr5L+Vm4iRraMCAmlKpKK26kCYdaeLv+5mqNBG7fhYvDd8WNZ+\
eEWlunEpjkI9O7GTU8G33mSo1dKBkTU0wbaZWi+o0+\
YvksMe8N05IQ28YEX8JZZrdpm7EEsoiH2tX//HUOZs3c9ppUt2Dg0Sdpi7fwsm0Ok1MfGQ\
NDESBUlnv+\
J2myqJVTIIYDmLgnCodpdvS334nrjNs7Sdz5tLJOSy2JoN1BvAPb9wJahqRqo4iJ+\
JBU7lm0nCNB5NGROTUhoZ5hBSrP/S7Ue+gDrnqMaKf082V5/\
JMGPHw80pwGhMXXrJJbtFEyY1CL33L2p6Z5EbIk448qlK8PHAOQp5C5JmmOSfeuMELFchZ\
xpMnCKPc5GHeupGHPHJd3ZIqQp6U5JHrxcsD51B6eW6fS3lkCAxreXmCMMpNHjnvh1T+\
VUpKS7iTkju1dvHuwDmU3p3zmfFUsDEJU+\
cR94qFyzNhlJs7tbzXLUB7NeqyYCcldnS5eHbgHErPTtT6hYzZyWBXPmCnYTvh6sRMd4Iw\
yo0dPe+3ucBV7tRlVbiTkjs7evHuwDmU3p3zme7s2M4gjXQnCKPc3NlJ8m7eZdyBwvWqJm\
tVaa216DVSgh4Oevza1KTYT87Zmk/GzsXg+NHmqPIG/\
1vA5Y0oczJ5j1Rmk3RCDFmWnJZhwcu42SfbqG4yBM8lZ3UaPjzc3Fp0VF5y4H1SdgGZjqo\
p4q11KXjjv2Rht9C31m3u5p7hxNQm6oVSpZquw6XN7GYQMn40MEaw+\
bDqGlbctVQkeHiwSfddmbKa96pwH42GJFXE5MBUcpxutbgFnBeD4/\
Op00hvFjIcYQR3EBc6e+G38RlcGQ73vj81sOt6a9CTwhPS9LaFdA/\
jWOCsTiOHR5w05gmGR0rW1sC/t1VtwVqHp/0PTPAHgpnFqQ1UIwqrqXBloK2+\
Kt9R0LaNrQmSXQ8pB+\
T0BkbPolPiZPbMaVsKnzjnEeJRnI8zSsX98CxasSvwWLNYH0yLueuxmOPePpD3MuYqF+\
dL5vbs4pzF3F0yQiI1a/yAtna7tUmPGAj94idZfj2Wir95rSv8K8C/jLZPPSf+\
xfmSrFH0ez81egKVIDEeiS8EtYjqcmsT2SVSMbx5KRPhlzo9e1fgV6JX7KSB3/\
6v37hGn9fnw7jpgIu0Ti/dmWHOH/mfBrqQbr50z5/UJSLVxVZWUdDNbWOR/xVAoOj/\
njEbVYUeYxY2JrWR1GUpbWTbWNgobBQ2RtmorAsb07KR1GUpbWTbWNgobBQ2RtnIblsvbE\
xqI6nLUtrItrGwUdgobIyysV2lW1bYmNRGUpeltJFtY2GjsFHYGGXjOrNPmbAxqY2kLktp\
I9vGwkZho7AxykZ2TaOwMfGzGHmjlDaybSxsFDYKG+\
faGKzMrcqLNwKA6W7KIb0ASsBIrV1R4q+QS2sXgAv+4RfbV/\
wmAPdYFxKukINL264qaqOuyZwq+VNu777rjenTXGal3NWgDUmzm06CHfQVvpVxqS38H+\
TMywtTXvSGUlW7ApklkXnWjza90L1GyPE/P8zEznxW2K/\
Obp8RQIdXm9Vp6OTGDRQb0E2VtTfTt491tIpUFzlNGtyQ2iyUmxpz5505bkJWbZWUm1eDx\
kPVdivp++BXpzGTa1pzkDMzcDVVpSbpktTqSEplbUdIs7Q0O9VqbGnYek8uDTn+\
WZfmbCU2O2PsHO6P3X5YbsP9OqDVaejwgPN6xFHj5DbVvNfZX51BR6sLc9IxRyvYHLpShT\
mZZjc7kN0YB3iE8SRhdgMxkzc2Wt6v4oDCurbhJzeiG5XC0HBxG8Re8A//+\
WGmLEPD14I2RLp7hDrYiEvNxSBqcu1HDYtRpi0pYrAmFWW2ilVmSyiTtzI3p8rI7lt3gZo\
eNpxREmq28qWGjqmsqbkSUAMdJyHN8tLo3UKl0SOmQJZfmrMzKHxj5SSPAVwS9JouBgGTq\
y90XGbtCwix25WUhhiXSYGX+3JhwzIX/MOXnZe9CF7OzqjM7aDtkO6Z5J9Q0+\
p72EG7Y2x4CZghgZP32Mxu3q+G9zmtRexpL/\
YWjGDmmaAWS7XZanjLiinMMT4otlrlyLCWnsIcHqhZwwfEwQbXSlPYt5R9z51UZKn4m9u+\
QsACBBSLOBYJODdW80JQovsoAsFkCEpyKRFk2lcgKBAsKYJMrOaFYF0gmA6C9XIiyLSvQF\
AgWFIEmVjNC8Hagr0CBYIxEKxVS4kg074CQYFgSRFkYjUWgv8HwRZK5g=="]
```

Timings

```
Do[xlookup["Banana", "Fruit", "Number", table], {10000}]; // RepeatedTiming (* {0.016786, Null} *)
Do[xlookup2["Banana", "Fruit", "Number", table], {10000}]; // RepeatedTiming (* {0.0386281, Null} *)
Do[myXLookup[table, "Fruit", "Banana", "Number"], {10000}]; // RepeatedTiming (* {0.0137247, Null} *)
```

and on the bigger table

```
Do[xlookup["YZCKN-RTN", "Musxgercux", "Xchxvg", table3], {10000}]; // RepeatedTiming (* {0.123693, Null} *)
Do[xlookup2["YZCKN-RTN", "Musxgercux", "Xchxvg", table3], {10000}]; // RepeatedTiming (* {0.134478, Null} *)
Do[myXLookup[table3, "Musxgercux", "YZCKN-RTN", "Xchxvg"], {10000}]; // RepeatedTiming (* {0.0102057, Null} *)
```

---

**Edit 2**

Make a bigger table:

```
SeedRandom[1];
numCols = 500;
colHeaders = RandomWord[numCols, IncludeInflections -> True];
colHeaders // DeleteDuplicates // Length ;(* 500 *)
numRows = 10000;
data = Table[RandomWord[500, IncludeInflections -> True], {i, numRows}];

table4 = AssociationThread[colHeaders, #] & /@ data;
```

Including `lookup`. It has some overhead but would be worth it depending how often you call your function

```
Do[xlookup["conceptual", "bluest", "evaluation", 
    table4], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming (*{0.5233793`,Null}*)
Do[xlookup2["conceptual", "bluest", "evaluation", 
    table4], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming(*{0.3965321`,Null}*)
Do[myXLookup[table4, "bluest", "conceptual", 
    "evaluation"], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming(*{0.000152`,Null}*)

lookup = newLookup[table4]; // RepeatedTiming(*{3.061114`,Null}*)
Do[lookup["bluest", "conceptual", 
    "evaluation"], {100}]; // AbsoluteTiming(*{0.0000843`,Null}*)
```

Comment: The eagle eyed will note that I have jumped from `table` to `table3` without `table2`. I apologize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll get an immediate bump with just better access patterns:

```
myXLookup[data_, searchKey_, searchValue_, accessKey_] :=
  Lookup[SelectFirst[data, #[searchKey] == searchValue &], accessKey]
```

I changed the signature a bit according to my tastes.

I hesitate to make any recommendations for futher speedup without knowing what the data actually looks like.

Comment: the data is a mix of strings, reals and integers with duplicates. I will edit and post a sample table

Comment: this gets the 10x speed-up compared to my function on "real" data!

Comment: Perhaps even simpler: `FirstCase[data, assoc : KeyValuePattern[{searchKey -> searchValue}] :> assoc[accessKey]]`. This is probably faster too because it can do everything through the pattern matcher.

Comment: Very fast, but not as fast as @lericr

Answer (score 2):

Solutions with `Cases`, `Select` or their variations or `Dataset[SelectFirst[...]]` iterate over data, which on large datasets, come with large performance hits. You did come close with `xlookup` but the result wasn't saved. Here I save the position of values, so no iteration happens.

First here are the numbers for my computer:

```
xlookup: 0.284065
myXLookup: 0.0251059
```

##### Code

```
ClearAll[newLookup];

newLookup[table_] := 
 newLookup[table, 
  AssociationThread[
   Keys[First@table] -> (PositionIndex /@ Transpose[Values /@ table])]]

newLookup[table_, indexedTable_][key1_, value1_, key2_] := 
 Extract[table, indexedTable[key1][value1]][key2]
```

If you happen to have two records with the same `value1`, you won't get the result, because a `indexedTable[key1]` should be `First@indexedTable[key1]`. I didn't want to cover all the edge cases. I also assume all records share the same set of keys.

##### Test

It has two stages, first, we compute the indexed table in order to save use time later, which returns a function you can use like before.

```
lookup = newLookup[table3]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {0.0007038, Null} *)


Do[lookup["Musxgercux", "YZCKN-RTN", "Xchxvg"];, 
   10000]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {0.0198539, Null} *)
```

On your data with `62` records, the difference is not noticeable, but if you test it on a large dataset, you will see the effect (and I like to hear the result ;).

Comment: This is super fast, another 10x in speed when I make table that is 500x10000 !

Comment: I picked @lericr answer as it fits my use case better but I will definitely use your function in other applications in future!